# iFrame causes webpage to scroll upwards when clicking on it

Tags: excel, iframe, scroll

I have an iframe incorporated into a webpage, this iframe consists of an excel sheet. The webpage is designed simply for the purposes of inputting a few numbers with a simple addition calculations to obtain an output (made with the excel sheet).

When I load the webpage and click onto one of the cells in the iframe, the webpage scrolls up right to the top automatically. This doesn't happen when you continually click inside the iframe. It only happens when you click outside the outside the iframe and then click inside again.

Does anyone have any suggestions to eliminate the problem of having the webpage scroll upwards? I know it's not a big problem, it just causes a nuisance to the webpage user.